# How do I define this reject method from the Gosu library tutorial?

Tags: ruby, methods, libgosu

I'm wondering how do define `reject` in this code from [the Gosu tutorial](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Ruby-Tutorial):

```
def collect_stars(star)
  if Star.reject! {|star| Gosu::distance(@x, @y, Star.x, star.y) < 35} then
    @score += 1
  end
end
```

Looking at the tutorial, I don't see where `reject` is defined. What would you do to define it?

Answer (score 0):

The code refers to `stars.reject!` which makes sense as that's probably the built-in Array [`reject!` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

```
def collect_stars(stars)
  if stars.reject! {|star| Gosu::distance(@x, @y, star.x, star.y) < 35 } then
    @score += 1
  end
end
```

What you've done here is switched it to `Star.reject!` which is completely different, it's acting against the class `Star`. I'm not sure what your intent is there.

Comment: I just rewrote from the tutorial. To be honest, I'm thinking of starting a different tutorial when I fix this stuff with better explanations in it.

Comment: I was trying to understand as I wrote it. So, I should switch "Star" to "stars?"

Comment: `Star` refers to the class, `stars` is the parameter passed in to the method. These are two completely different things, so yes, it's an important difference.

Comment: I still get the same error:

"in 'collect_stars' undefined method 'reject!' "

Comment: You're going to have to check what `stars` is. Try debugging: `raise stars.inspect`